# Display Prime numbers with MVC Java

Tags: java, model-view-controller, primes

I have a Prime class which extends JFrame and it has a simple JSpinner for displaying prime numbers.

I want to create a Model for displaying prime numbers infinitely (until long ends). Here is the model class I have written:

```
public class PrimeSpinnerModel extends AbstractSpinnerModel{

    long current;

    public PrimeSpinnerModel() {
        this.current = 2;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValue() {
        return current;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getNextValue() {

        long newLatest = current + 1;

        if(isPrime(newLatest)){
            current = newLatest;
        }else{
            System.out.println(newLatest + "no prime");
            newLatest ++;
            current = newLatest;  
        }
        fireStateChanged(); 
        return getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getPreviousValue() {

        fireStateChanged();
        return getValue(); // without this the component wouldn't know to update.
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(Object value) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Static spinner model Prime does not support editing.");
    }
    static boolean isPrime(long n) {
        if (n == 1) return false;

        for(long i = 2; i <= n/2; i++)
            if(n % i == 0)
                return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

When I run the code, it displays prime numbers as 2,3,5,7,9,11,13 etc.

Why 9 is displayed?

Comment: Solve what? What's the problem?

Comment: I guess 9 being displayed as prime is the problem?

Comment: It shouldn't display 9 as a prime number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose current is 7 when `getNextValue()` is invoked. Then newLatest is set to 8. `isPrime(8)` is obviously false, so then you increment newLatest, making it 9. You assign it to current and return it. This makes 9 the next number after seven, regardless of whether it is prime or not.

To solve this, you should increment newLatest while it is not prime (in a loop). That way, you ensure you continue until you found a prime number. See below:

```
newLatest = current + 1;
while (!isPrime(newLatest)) {
    newLatest++;
}
// newLatest now contains the new prime number.
current = newLatest;
// etc..
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
  public static void showPrimeNumbers(int n){
        for (int i=2; i<n; i++){
          boolean istrue = true;
          for (int x=2; x<i; x++){
            if  (i%x==0){
                istrue = false;
            }
           }

           if  (istrue==true){
               System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }
```